# How to properly initialize a var type

Tags: c#, initialization

I have this piece of code:

```
DatabaseContext dbContext = modul.CreateContext();

var returnvalue = dbContext.tbl_person
    .ToArray()
    .Select(item => new PersonGridRow
        {
            PersonID = item.PersonID,
            ...
        });
```

I need to make it more dynamic, so it uses the same selection, but with different table.

I would like to do something like this:

```
DatabaseContext dbContext = modul.CreateContext();
var selection;
if(some condition)
{
    selection = dbContext.tbl_person;
}
else
{
    selection = dbContext.tbl_personHistory
}

var returnvalue = selection
    .ToArray()
    .Select(item => new PersonGridRow
        {
            PersonID = item.PersonID,
            ...
        });
```

Both tables are identical. I know that var is not a type, but rather a figure at execution time what the type is. I have tried using dynamic keyword as well, but without success.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Var is not derived at runtime - it is already derived at compile time.

Comment: `Both tables are identical.`... you know that, but the compiler does not. What happened when you tried to use `dynamic`?

Comment: You can use object...

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: `object` does not have a `ToArray` method.

Comment: if you aren't assigning a value at declaration var has no way to infer the type.

Comment: Can I solve this on another way?

Comment: How about using an interface or a base type?

Comment: When I use dynamic, I get the following error: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

Comment: My knowledge is not good enough that I can use interface. Any example would be a good pointer.

Comment: Why not just write out whatever base type `tbl_person` and `tbl_personHistory` have in common? Judging from your code, `IEnumerable<...>` should do, where `...` is the type of items they contain.

Comment: Just create an interface the defines the same properties between both tables and add that interface to the entitiy objects.  Something like `IPerson` then just to `condition ? (IEnumerable<IPerson>)tbl_person : tbl_personHistory`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I would have to define all of the properties of the table, the thing is I have lots of properties already. Care to show me an example?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet You'd need to use `IQueryable`, not `IEnumerable`, to ensure that the queries are executed at the database, rather than in memory.  Also, you're assuming there is already a common type; I doubt that's the case.

Comment: Are you using code first to db generated?  Either way if both field sets match between the tables just change the entity model from PersonHistory on tbl_personHistory to Person then go with my response.  Otherwise you will need to duplicate all of the properties you wish to use on the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface that represents the data that these tables have in common:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    int PersonID {get;}
    //...
}
```

Then have both of the entity types for the two tables you're using implement that interface.  Once you do that you can declare the variable using that interface:

```
DatabaseContext dbContext = modul.CreateContext();
IQueryable<IPerson> selection;
if(some condition)
    selection = dbContext.tbl_person;
else
    selection = dbContext.tbl_personHistory

var returnvalue = selection
    .Select(item => new PersonGridRow
        {
            PersonID = item.PersonID,
            ...
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

```
var select = something == otherthing ? 
    dbContext.tbl_person.Select(item => new PersonGridRow
    {
        PersonID = item.PersonID,
        ...
    }) :
    dbContext.tbl_personHistory.Select(item => new PersonGridRow
    {
        PersonID = item.PersonID,
        ...
    });
```

Other techniques would include changing the base type on your `personHistory` table in the model browser in EF to be the same entity as the `person` table. You could then just do this...

```
 var select = (
        something == otherthing ? 
            dbContext.tbl_person : 
            dbContext.tbl_personHistory
    ).Select(item => new PersonGridRow
    {
        PersonID = item.PersonID,
        ...
    });
```

Another options would be to assign and interface with all of the shared properties then cast the first table to `IQueryable<IPerson>` or 'IEnumerable`

```
 var select = (
        something == otherthing ? 
            (IQueryable<IPerson>)dbContext.tbl_person : 
            dbContext.tbl_personHistory
    ).Select(item => new PersonGridRow
    {
        PersonID = item.PersonID,
        ...
    });
```

Lastly you could create a view on the server side that does a `union all` between `person` and `personHistory` the use this view as the basis of your query.

Comment: That won't work. Both types of a ternary expression must be the same.

Comment: Dude please learn to code.  If they types are the same it will work.  We don't know the types because he didn't show the declaration.

Comment: btw, I have personally used the same entity types for mutiple table referenes so don't tell me it's not possible.

Comment: This is not working. "type of cinditional expression cannot be determined becaouse there is no implicit conversion between System.Data.Linq.table<db.tbl_person> and System.Data.Linq.table<db.tbl_personHistory"

Comment: And there we are. @MatthewWhited perhaps you could modify your answer to show the OP how to make the types the same?

Comment: Whole point of this is to make code smaller. In JavaScript I can easy do this.

Comment: BTW, @Wexoni, you could also change the udner tpying types if the columns match (or are at least close) between the two tables/views.

Comment: Javascript is a dynamic language.  C# is static. EF is based on knowing the type so even if you try casting to `dynamic` or `object` EF would throw runtime errors.

Comment: You could also add an interface to the entities and then `.Cast<..>()`  to that interface before you try to select between the two tables.

Comment: Why are so many people upvoting an answer that in no way actually solves the problem being asked?  The whole point of the question is to avoid repeating the `Select` query.

Comment: That's not the original question.  Of he keeps changing the goal post then enjoy continuing to down vote.

Comment: @MatthewWhited It's *exactly* what the original question was.  The only changes to the question was adding a tag and some minor formatting changes, neither of which were even made by the OP.  You just didn't understand the question that was originally asked.  Considering that there's a revision history that specifically shows that nothing meaningful has been changed, I have no idea why you'd use such an easily disprove excuse.

Comment: Wahhhhhhhhh... Someone else got more votes.  That's all I heard :)